# how to read only y-axis from file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to draw a line chart form the data in a file that consist two line: one line for APPL stock and one for NFLX stock. x-axis is a time. I cannot figure out how to point that y is numbers from a file.

Text: 
120.96, 120.95, 120.72, 120.77, 120.92, 121.1, 121.26, 121.63, 121.68, 121.56, 121.59, 121.5, 121.52, 121.4, 121.33, 121.31, 121.47, 121.58, 121.785, 121.76, 121.55, 121.4308, 121.47, 121.45, 121.4699, 121.53, 121.5, 121.6399, 121.6, 121.525, 121.29, 121.28, 121.125, 121.18, 121.28, 121.145, 121.16, 121.11, 121.26, 121.43, 121.4, 121.289, 121.32, 121.39, 121.2898, 121.33, 121.28, 121.46, 121.32, 121.35, 121.26, 121.07, 121.09, 121.083, 121.08,.....

113.36, 113.21, 113.3, 113.33, 113.56, 113.805, 113.81, 113.76, 113.75, 113.896, 113.75, 113.43, 113.44, 113.29, 113.253, 113.17, 113.39, 113.36, 113.65, 113.9, 113.65, 113.51, 113.51, 113.5, 113.3, 113.39, 113.278, 113.105, 113.011, 113.0, 112.839, 112.879, 112.85, 113.026, 112.915, 112.878, 112.88, 112.74, 112.91, 112.78, 112.775, 112.725, 112.69, 112.62, 112.61, 112.73, 112.6, 112.79, 112.746, 112.77, 112.66, 112.46, 112.54, 112.585, ....

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = open('AAPL-NFLX.txt', 'r')

stock_list = f.read().split(',')
line_1 = stock_list[:391]
line_2 = stock_list[391:]

x = np.linspace(0, 391) 
y = line_1[0::2]
z = line_2[0::2]

plt.plot(x, y, 'y--', label='APPL') 
plt.plot(x, z, 'r-', label='NFLX')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.xlabel("Time in Minutes")
plt.ylabel("Stock Price")
```

Answer (score 0):

### What are you asking ?

Here is how I would read the first column of a file into a list.

```
with open('AAPL-NFLX.txt', 'r') as f:
    stock_list = [line.split(',')[0] for line in f.readline()]
```

You open a file (`with` statement for confort and readability), and iterate over the lines (with a list comprehension over the f.readline()) and take the first element once split from file.

#### CSV powaaa

One important point though : If you're having CSV files (coma-separated values), not just unformatted text with commas somewhere, use the dedicated [python csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) :

```
with open('AAPL-NFLX.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    stock_list = [line[0] for line in reader]
```

This allows for easier readability and maintenance (for instance changing newline delimiter to `;`, line skipping, reading to dictionary ...)

### Numpy CSV reader

For fancy things like reading CSV into Numpy arrays at lightspeed, you can use the amazing (if complex) [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Optimized like hell.

> numpy.loadtxt(fname, dtype=, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0)[source]

Your code becomes

```
stock_list = numpy.loadtxt('AAPL-NFLX.txt',dtype=float,usecols=1)
```

Boom. Mind blown.

Comment: I use .txt file. how to code that every number in a line is going to be "y" value?

Comment: I do not know how to identify here x and y, z to draw two line charts. Can you help?

Comment: Oh. `plt.plot(x,y,label='Plot number 1');plt.legend()`.
You add label info to each plot line and call matplotlib's legend function.
See more at http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html.
If that's your question, I'll edit my answer for that